# Chart.js line chart display decimal values on Y axis

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, chart.js

I'm dealing with an ASP.NET MVC5 application which makes use of Chart.js library to display a line chart.
I am not able to display decimal values on the Y axis.
The values appear as integer on the chart. Any idea why?

```
float[] currentTemperatureArray = ViewBag.valuesArray;
string[] labelsArray = ViewBag.labelsArray;
<script>
var chartLabels = [];
var chartValuesCT = [];
        @{
        for (int i = 0; i < labelsArray.Length; i++)
        {
                @:chartLabels[@i] = "@labelsArray[i]";
                    }
    }

    @{
        for (int i = 0; i < currentTemperatureArray.Length; i++)
        {
                         @:chartValuesCT[@i] = @currentTemperatureArray[i];
                     }
var lineChartData =
                        {
                            labels: chartLabels,
                            datasets : [
                            {
                                label: "Current Temperature",
                                format: '{value:.5f}',
                                fillColor : "rgba(220,220,220,0.2)",
                                strokeColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                pointColor : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                                data: chartValuesCT
                            }]}
            window.onload = function(){
                var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
                ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
                ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
                    scaleOverride : true,
                    scaleSteps : 1,
                    scaleStepWidth : 20,
                    scaleStartValue : -20,
                    responsive: true
                });
            }
    </script>
```

Comment: You might want to add your values and a screenshot as well. Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in how the decimal numbers are formatted. Apparently there is an error by converting the number from .NET to javascript. The comma versus dot standard seems to be important here.

Comment: Can you explain this further as to whether the decimals were already being converted and you needed to change it or if you had to change the value to a string and convert the decimal replacing . with , or ...?